# File.Exists - Wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

i'm trying to see if the picture exists but this says that isnt there, and the path is correct!
The path is correct, and it has a picture, but this allways go to "else".

```
string path = @"c:\folder\pic.jpg";

if (File.Exists(path))
{ 
    //Do something here 
}
else 
{
}
```

Comment: you have to take the absolute path of the file not the directory itself.

Comment: -1: It’s unhelpful when the nature of the question is changed entirely by correcting a negligent mistake. With the edit, all answers except Skeet’s are irrelevant.

Comment: Just remove the check (it's not foool-proof anyway) and open the file. If there is an exception you'll learn something.

Comment: If you are running this from IIS then the user account your application pool is running under must have read access to this directory.  The easiest way to do this is to give the IIS_USRS account (win vista / 7 / 2008) account access to the folder.  Otherwise move the directory to inside where the application lives.

Comment: @Henk - it depends on the scenario.  For test projects / dev it's fine to have them outside the running app directory.  In a production environment it will never fly.  Based on the question - I doubt this is for a production app with security implications.

Comment: For example the source code on my dev machine has this account added as I run my debug builds using IIS but not inside an IIS directory.  There is no way I am going to move / copy files all over the place for a simple debugging session.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be a permissions issue. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

> If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.

Of course, this means you're more likely to see this issue when you're running a web app (which typically runs under reduced permissions) than a client app.

Additionally, as noted in deerchao's comment, `File.Exists` only returns true if the path given is to a *file*, not a directory. Again, from the documentation:

> If path describes a directory, this method returns false.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to see if a *folder* exists using `File.Exists`. This is not correct - it will fail for directories.

Use [`Directory.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) for finding if a directory exists.

```
string path = @"c:\folder";

if (Directory.Exists(path))
{ 
    //Do something here 
}
else 
{
}
```

An additional complication is that the account your application is running under needs to have the permissions to read the path - if it doesn't have the permissions, this will still fail even if the path exists.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are trying to check whether any file exists within the specified directory? In that case, you may use:

```
string path = @"c:\folder";

if (Directory.Exists(path) &&
    Directory.GetFiles(path).Any())
{
    //Do something here 
}
else
{
}
```

In .NET 4 and later, you may optimize the second check by replacing the `GetFiles` call with `EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that is a file/picture not a directory!

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano: It would help if you would choose more appropriate filenames in future then. The name "folder" strongly suggests a folder/directory, not a file.